# JXTreeTable - my node is editable but other cells are not

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

This is really confusing me. I will show my code so far.
I am trying to make certain field's editable. That is the end goal, but I just tried to put in a JCheckBox just to test. But even that doesn't seem to work.

Can you please take a look at this. I would really appreciate it.

All the JXTreeTable does is make my nodes editable. which I don't want as well as if I do change my node, its edit will save through the whole row which too I don't really want.

Here is what I have done:

**Intialization**

```
JXTreeTable table = new JXTreeTable(Shared.model);
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new ComplexCellEditor());
table.setRootVisible(false);
table.setEditable(true);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
table.setColumnControlVisible(true);
```

**This is my ComplexCellEditor.java**

```
class ComplexCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
public ComplexCellEditor() {
    super(new JTextField());
    Console.t("here");
}
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean a, boolean b, int row)
{
    Component component = super.getTreeCellEditorComponent(tree, value, isSelected, a , b, row);

        Console.t("here");   <--**//THIS DOESN'T EVEN GET PRINTED**
        JCheckBox chk= new JCheckBox();
        return chk;
}
```

}

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Make sure your `TreeTableModel` returns true for `isCellEditable`.

Comment: @Max: put that as your answer and I will give you credit. thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `TreeTableModel` returns true for `isCellEditable`.

Comment: there are 2 isCellEditable methods  :DDD